# Visual Studio 2019 - Device Button is Missing Hololens Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2019, hololens-emulator

I am missing the hololens emulator on the device button drop down in Visual Studio 2019.

1. I am using the community edition of Visual Studio.
2. I have hyper-v enabled.
3. I am using Windows 10 Pro.
4. I ran the HoloLensEmulatorSetup.exe and restarted my computer.
5. I am meeting everything on the checklist located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools).

What should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happened. I am not sure why this did the trick but at least my problem is solved now.

I removed each project, in Visual Studio, and tried running everything 1 at a time. I also restarted Visual Studio between openings.

That seemed to do the trick. Everything works fine now.